# jquery set base href

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to set the base href with JQuery by reading a PHP file.

Why does `$("base").load("ip.php");` work but `$("base[property='href']").load("ip.php");` doesn't?

Of course what I need is to set the href parameter only, not the content of base.
I found I could get it working by using `$("head").load("ip.php");` but would like to know why above isn't working.

Comment: what do you mean with "this work" `$("base").load("ip.php");`, how do this set the href of base? or this: `$("head").load("ip.php");` ??

Comment: `load` doesn't change the href attribute, it loads content from your ip.php and puts it into `base`element, if you want to change href you can do `$('base').attr('href', 'ip.php')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this to set href value

```
   $('base').attr('href','http://www.google.com');
```

Its depend how your file ip.php is

For example

ip.php

```
<?php 
   echo 'http://www.google.com';

?>
```

Then

```
$.get('ip.php',function(response){
    $("base").attr("href", response);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly, but in my opinion, u got the meaning of the selector wrong. I think   [property='href']  is not a valid selector. href is the property you should search for, and not the value.

You can select DOM-elements with jquery using $("base"). Additionally you can use a key-value combination to search for certain attribute-values of your element.

```
$("a[href$='.org']")
```

With this selector you would select  elements with a href attribute which ends with '.org'.

So the point is: you still select the DOM-element and NOT a part of that element. But your search is better specified.

Comment: you're right I got the selector meaning wrong, you didn't answer however how I can set the href value...

Comment: @sarah.ferguson have a look at the [jQuery API documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/general-attributes/), mainly to the `attr` method

Answer (score 0):

just need :

> window.location = "http://yoursite.php";

Comment: But that is not the thing, she wants to do.   window.location  is a javascript function, which will redirect your browser to the new location. Sarah wants to load some data and set it as 'href' attribute to a html element in her page.

Answer (score 0):

dont use load, use $.ajax!

```
$.ajax({
    url: "ip.php"
}).done(function (data) {
    $("base").attr("href", data);
});
```